# Spring Web Application Issue (MVC) Status 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I know this is a lot of code to throw out there but I'd appreciate it if someone can help me figure out the problem. It's just a basic MVC, there's only one link on the main page, "Login", and when clicked it should take you to login.jsp. However, it fails to do so. I believe the problem is with the controller because the annotations in the controller file are light grey (using intellij idea) as if they're not being used. "/login" does show up in the url.

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml (config):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nusuth.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**loginController.java:**

```
package com.nusuth.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class loginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadLoginPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a login.jsp in the jsp folder right? and also add  log output in your question, it will be much helpful.

Comment: That is correct, login.jsp is in a jsp folder. I included the log output above. Thanks.

Comment: if you are using any logger try setting the log level to debug which will enable a detailed lookup into the root cause

Comment: That sounds great. How do I do that?

Comment: this link will help http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/

Comment: Not sure if it's working but I installed the log4j.jar. I did notice this in the debug log: 23-Jan-2016 21:40:42.667 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet spring as unavailable
23-Jan-2016 21:40:42.670 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [spring] in web application [] threw load() exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Comment: extract your war file. Check if all the required library present in WEB-INF/libs

Comment: @muninn9 what is the error message u r getting with 404 error?

Comment: make sure your have added spring-mvc and spring-context jars as dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also write "login" controller as:

```
@Controller
public class loginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new LoginForm()); // empty login form
        return "login"; //jsp page name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Muninn9,
I did notice your web.xml, it is missing ContextLoaderListener configuration,  which eventually loads and initialize your bean container.
 Add your log4j.xml/log4j.properties to web.xml and use this listener (Log4jConfigListener) which will enable your console logs.
Ensure you have a valid log4j.xml/log4j.properties in your project classpath settings.

Comment: How do you use a listener?

Comment: You can find in spring community forum, please use your search criteria as Spring MVC+ contextloaderListener

Answer (score 0):

From your log message I can see that catalina didn't found required class SpringServlet.

Which means required libraries wasn't included with the web project. All the required libraries of a web application should be in WEB-INF/lib directory.

if you use a build tool such as MAVEN or gradle it will they will handle it automatically.

Else you can

> 1. Create a folder WEB-INF/libs
> 2. Put all the required libraries there.

IntelliJ idea creates a directory named **libs** in your home directory and put all the libraries there if choose the option to download the libraries automatically. You can copy that directory to **WEB-INF** also

Answer (score 0):

Fix you *schema* configuration to :

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd"
```

otherwise  `<mvc:annotation-driven />` won't be registered correctly.

Here I fixed everything for you :

[image]

*spring-servlet.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nusuth.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*login.jsp*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello This is login page!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

*loginController.java*

```
package com.nusuth.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class loginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadLoginPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Now request the *login.jsp* with :

*http://localhost:8080/LoginDemo/login*

Comment: Are you kidding? this will work just fine. If no then there's configuration and dependecy problems you got there.

Comment: Gotcha, that must be the problem then.

Comment: Btw put *attention* correctly on the directory structure in my answer.